# R - Extracting worksheet style and copying into a different workbook

Tags: r, xlconnect

I would like to copy the entire sheet (retaining the style) from one workbook into another workbook.

I tried cloneSheet() from the XLConnect package but I'm not sure if it can be used to clone a worksheet to a different workbook.

I also tried createSheet() to create a new sheet in workbook_1.xlsx then, readWorksheet() in workbook_2.xlsx, and finally writeWorksheet() to write the data from workbook_2 to workbook_1, but only the data gets transferred and not the style.

Thanks in advance for any inputs.

Comment: Try `openxlsx::cloneWorksheet` instead of `XLConnect`.

Comment: I think  openxlsx::cloneWorksheet  has the same limitation as cloneSheet() where it can only clone within the same workbook, unless it's possible to save the workbook as an object and then append to a different workwork.

Comment: I think you're right. After `wb <- openxlsx::loadWorkbook(...)`, if you look at `ls.str(wb)`, you'll see a lot of content that suggests you might be able to copy the sheet brute-force by copying over specific components. I think there are a lot of places where one might miss something, so I doubt this is trivial. I don't have the time at the moment to dive into it, but I thought you might be able to figure something out. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.This has been solved with a very different approach via win32com.